# Why does my bottom navigation view only contain the text of the first item?

Tags: android, android-layout

I want my navigation bar to include the icon and text of all items, however I am only getting the text and icon for the first item (the rest only display the icon).

It seems it is dependent on the order, as I have switched the order of the items and only the first item displays both logo and icon. This means that there is no syntax error in the rest of the items as they are all behaving the same way.

```
<com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"

        app:itemBackground="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:itemIconTint="@android:color/white"
        app:itemTextColor="@android:color/white"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/linear"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/linear"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_menu" />
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">


    <item
        android:id="@+id/Home"
        android:enabled="true"

        android:icon="@drawable/baseline_home_white_18dp"
        android:title="@string/home"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText"
       />


    <item
        android:id="@+id/Social"

        android:enabled="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/baseline_public_white_18dp"
        android:title="Social"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/Diagnoses"


        android:enabled="true"

        android:icon="@drawable/baseline_image_search_white_18dp"
        android:title="@string/diagnoses"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/Inbox"
        android:title="Artists"
        android:enabled="true"

        android:icon="@drawable/baseline_inbox_white_18dp"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/rewards"


        android:enabled="true"

        android:icon="@drawable/baseline_store_mall_directory_white_18dp"
        android:title="@string/rewards"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText" />



</menu>
```

I expect the text and icon to be on every item, however the text is only showing on the first item (doesn't matter which item is placed first).

[image: Example of item text]

Answer (score 1):

Add this method to your BottomNavigationView:

```
app:labelVisibilityMode="labeled"
```

Answer (score 0):

When setting e.g.`itemTextColor` you should use a selector instead of a color to support the checked state.

> res/color/selector_bottom_navigation.xml

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:color="#fff" android:state_checked="false"  />
    <item android:color="#000" />
</selector>
```

Comment: Just put it into `res/color`.

Comment: unfortunately, this solution didnt affect the layout... first item is still the only item to show the text